# Limit loop count for refreshid Jquery?

Tags: jquery, loops, count, limit, repeat

I am sure I have this butchered, but I am trying to limit how many times the `refreshID` variable repeats, not the delay, but the total amount. If someone can help to keep it simple, I would really appreciate it.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    count = 0;
    limit = 5;

    var refreshId = setInterval( function(){
        $( ".feed-load-more-container .yt-uix-button" ).click(); }, 5000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `clearInterval()` method. So inside your anonymous function, check to see if count < limit. If it is, proceed and increment count. If it's not, then clear the interval.

Like so:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

count = 0; limit = 5;

var refreshId = setInterval( function() {
    if(count < limit) {
        $( ".feed-load-more-container .yt-uix-button" ).click();
        count++;
    }
    else {
        clearInterval(refreshId);
    }
    }, 5000);

});
```

Comment: This lets me automatically load more videos on youtube with out clicking, thanks again

Comment: Glad to help. This community helps me when I have troubles :)

Comment: This also auto clicks add url to playlist every 5 seconds to save time            $(document).ready(function()
{
  var refreshId = setInterval( function() 
 {
$( ".playlist-add-video-url-button-add" ).click();
  
    }, 5000);
});